# How would you get a JSONPath to all child nodes in an array of JSON object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonpath

How would you get a JSONPath to all child node of an object?

E.g.:

```
var data = [{
    "key1": {
        "children": [{
            "key2": "value",
            "key3": "value",
            "key4": {}
        }, {
            "key2": "value",
            "key3": "value",
            "key4": {}
        }],
        "key5": "value"
    }
}, {
    "key1": {
        "children": {
            "key2": "value",
            "key3": "value",
            "key4": {}
        },
        "key5": "value"
    }
}]
```

I want to get absolute path for all nodes in the data structure as an array:

```
[
    "data[0]['key1']['children'][0]['key2']", 
    "data[0]['key1']['children'][0]['key3']", 
    "data[0]['key1']['children'][0]['key4']", 
    ......, 
    "data[0]['key1']['children'][1]['key2']",
    ......., 
    "data[1]['key1']['children']['key2']",
    ..........
]
```

Is there any way to get this done in JS?

Comment: Yes, I suppose there are many ways to do it... Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Ok, I understand the term "JSONPath" (based on the tag description, it makes sense (the comparison between to XPath and XML seems appropriate)). But you are not working with JSON in your example, hence I will edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I'm confused in how to right the recursive function.

Comment: Does this help? https://code.google.com/p/jsonpath/

Comment: You might want to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json.

Comment: @elclanrs I'm looking for some simple custom code. Will try this too

Comment: @FelixKling: I Can write it manually, but I was looking for a code that generates array of JSON path when JSON array is given as input

Comment: There is no native function that does that. You have to write your own or use an existing external library. Regarding your edit, [there is no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). You are confusing object literals with JSON.

Comment: @FelixKling: I have to write recursive function right? I'm too weak in that :)

Comment: That's why I said have a look at the other question. It provides to examples of recursive functions to traverse nested data structures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote a custom code that gives us JSON path of all nodes as array

```
function toArray(obj, name) {
    var result = [];
    var passName;
    var tempArray = [];
    for (var prop in obj) {
        var value = obj[prop];
        if (typeof value === 'object') {
            if ($.isNumeric(prop)) {
                passName = name + "[" + prop + "]";
            } else {
                passName = name + "['" + prop + "']";
            }
            tempArray = toArray(value, passName);
            $.each(tempArray, function (key, value) {
                result.push(value);
            });

        } else {
            result.push(name + "['" + prop + "']");
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c5K3r/23/)

Answer (score 3):

well , I think you have to loop through your entire json structure..

```
  for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
     for(var j in data[i]){
       //and so on
      }
   }
```

Or simply you can create aleas arrary for every key where key will be the path of that value with "_" as separator like..

```
 var aleasArray = []; 
 for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
     for(var j in data[i]){
      aleasArray[i + '_' + j] = data[i][j];  // if you want make it more generalize aleas array..
      }
   }
```

hope this will help you..

Comment: What about the path of nested arrays