# How to repopulate form with multidimensional JSON data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, multidimensional-array

I am trying to find a way to populate form with multitiude of option types, selects , radios, texareas, checkboxes. I found few scripts like jQuery populate plugin or suggestions here [Using jQuery and JSON to populate forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298364/using-jquery-and-json-to-populate-forms)  and many more stack posts but none of them handle the multidimensional JSON data properly. This is the small sample of JSON data I am dealing with ,

```
var jsonData = {
    "get_template": "clean",
    "site_width": "1200px",
    "layout_type": "full",
    "main_contained": {
        "picked": "contained",
        "notcontained": {
            "container_contained": "contained"
        }
    },
    "container_spacing": "25",
    "columns_spacing": "25",
    "sidebars_spacing": {
        "horizontal": "50",
        "vertical": "50"
    },
    "headers": "menuright",
    "menu_template": "menuinheader",
    "toplevel_font": {
        "font": "Open Sans|600|latin|uppercase|default",
        "size": "12",
        "letterspacing": "0",
        "css": "font-family:&#039;Open Sans&#039;,sans-serif;font-weight:600;font-style:normal;font-size:12px;text-transform:uppercase;",
        "google_font_link": "Open Sans:600&subset=latin"
    },
    "sublevel_font": {
        "font": "Open Sans|regular|latin|none|default",
        "size": "14",
        "letterspacing": "0",
        "css": "font-family:&#039;Open Sans&#039;,sans-serif;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;font-size:14px;",
        "google_font_link": "Open Sans:regular&subset=latin"
    },

    "footer_switch": 1,
    "show_button": {
        "picked": "hide",
        "show": {
            "button": {
                "button_text": "Load more",
                "html": "<div class=\"btn-container grid-item-more\"><a class=\"button btn-small radius-4 btn-border-1 align-center btn-trans\" href=\"#\"><span class=\"btn-text fs-13 fw-600\">more</span></a></div>",
                "json": "{\"createButton\":\"on\",\"buttonTransition\":\"on\",\"buttonAnimation\":false}"
            }
        }
    },
    "img-smaller": {
        "max-width": "260",
        "max-height": "145"
    },
    "img-xsmall": {
        "max-width": "120",
        "max-height": "65"
    },
    "img-related": {
        "max-width": "350",
        "max-height": "350"
    },
    "custom_css": 0,
    "disable_admin_bar": false,
    "footer_section": {
        "json": "[{\"type\":\"section\",\"shortcode\":\"section_e603095\",\"width\":\"\",\"_items\":[{\"type\":\"columns\",\"shortcode\":\"columns_a9ae4ee\",\"width\":\"1_3\",\"options\":{\"widget_name\":\"Widget 1\",\"widget_in_boxstyle\":{\"padding\":{\"top\":\"0\",\"right\":\"0\",\"bottom\":\"0\",\"left\":\"0\"}]"
    }

};
```

and as you can see  the form can have text , json, booleans, and so on as values.

Form input names are prefixed like this  `fw_options[link_color]`  or `fw_options[main_contained][picked]`

**If I could ad least find a way to properly loop trough this json to rebuild the input names in the right way I might get a way with just checking the input type and setting its value.**

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the code will be a mess, buts here's what you need to do.

- Figure out how to loop for all of them, unfortunately I can only suggest that somewhere you call itself with a child such the below code using mock variables:

  ```
  function jsonloop(looper){ //pass in object/array to loop through
      if(lastchild){ //if last child of the lower part
          upperchild++; //go to next child of upper part
          jsonloop(upperchild);
      }
  }
  ```
- Use `instanceof` to check the type:

  ```
  if(json instanceof Array){
      for(var item in json){
          var jsonarray = json[item];
          //do stuff
      }
  } else if(json instance of Object){
      for(var item in json){
          var jsonobject = json[item];
          //do different stuff like below
          for(var name in jsonobject){ //loop through object properties
              //do other stuff
          }
      }
  }
  ```

**This is all mock code!**

Do not use as it is, it will not end well. Note: The end result will likely be semi-massive due to stuff like, `"json": [{}]` where is both an object and an array, and you're code will bomb. Here are some good resources:

- [JSON name iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876485/how-to-iterate-through-property-names-of-javascript-object)
- [Convert to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18629366/how-would-you-get-a-jsonpath-to-all-child-nodes-in-an-array-of-json-object) (may or may not be useful).
- [Find if json array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996871/why-does-typeof-array-with-objects-return-object-and-not-array) (also works with object, just replace with Object).

Good luck. I'm sorry, I couldn't build more.